# What is the best platform to become an online French teacher ?

Tags: professions

Good morning ! :)

I lived in the USA for 7 years where I worked as a French teacher in a private school. I have now been back in France for a few months. Language teaching is really my passion and I would like to get into teaching French online. I already have experience in distance education (thanks covid).

I did some research and came across some interesting platforms for teaching languages ​​remotely:

- AmazingTalker [ https://www.amazingtalker.fr/ ]
- Italki [ https://www.italki.com/ ]
- Superprof [ https://www.superprof.fr/ ]

As I want to make it a "long-term professional project", I would like to have some outside opinions before I start.

Have any of you used any of these platforms? Or even all three? Both as a teacher and a student. What was your feeling? Which of the platforms is the most "user friendly"?

Thanks in advance !! :)

Comment: I haven't used these platforms, but here is one that I've browsed through quite a bit (looking for an Italian tutor). Each teacher has a video so that you can get a good sense of their style: https://languatalk.com/

Comment: https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/82841/language-learning